# improve performance of Sql procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Sql procedure which select records from a table and if it matches insert to a different table.It is as follows

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MarkCopyData] 
@copyDataOperationId int,
@countryCode nvarchar(50),
@batchCount int,@batchId int,@jobId int
    AS
    BEGIN
DECLARE @TableObjectId AS Int;
SET @TableObjectId = OBJECT_ID('Table1');
INSERT INTO  
    Table2(
            TableObjectId, 
            SourcePrimaryKey, 
            DestinationCopyOperationId, 
            IsModifiedAftertCopied,IsDeleted,BatchId,JobId)

    SELECT TOP (@batchCount) @TableObjectId, tbl1.pkid, @copyDataOperationId,      0,0,@batchId,@jobId
    FROM [dbo].[Table1] AS tbl1
    Inner join [dbo].[Country] AS C on C.CountryId =  tbl1.fkid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 tbl2 on (tbl2 .SourcePrimaryKey = tbl1.pkid and tbl2 .TableObjectId = @TableObjectId)
    WHERE C.CountryCode = @countryCode AND tbl2.DestinationCopyOperationId IS NULL
    SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
    END
    GO
```

Can anybody please suggest tips to improve performance of this procedure

Comment: Analyze the execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the structure for the underlying tables it is impossible to help. Try using CTRL+L to view the estimated execution plan. You may want to comment out the `CREATE PROCEDURE` stuff, it'll make the plan easier to read.

Usually, it'll be a case of creating an index or two.

You may find that moving the `C.CountryCode = @countryCode` from the `WHERE` clause into the `INNER JOIN` may help a little. Generally, you want to filter your resultset before you start doing outer joins.

```
SELECT TOP (@batchCount) @TableObjectId, tbl1.pkid, @copyDataOperationId,0,0,@batchId,@jobId
FROM [dbo].[Table1] AS tbl1
Inner join [dbo].[Country] AS C on C.CountryId =  tbl1.fkid AND C.CountryCode = @countryCode
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 tbl2 on (tbl2 .SourcePrimaryKey = tbl1.pkid and tbl2 .TableObjectId = @TableObjectId)
WHERE tbl2.DestinationCopyOperationId IS NULL
```